# Racket equivalent of /dev/null?

Tags: racket

If I have a function that prints to `(current-output-port)`, is there an easy way to run the function without it printing to the output port?

Previously, I've used `/dev/null` as an output target:

```
(with-output-to-file "/dev/null" #:exists 'append
  (lambda () (displayln "hello world")))
```

This is easy, but platform dependent. Also I'll sometimes forget the `#:exists` flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! Use [`open-output-nowhere`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html?#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._open-output-nowhere%29%29) from [racket/port](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html).

```
(parameterize ([current-output-port (open-output-nowhere)])
  (displayln "hello world"))
```

If you want to hide error output, override [`current-error-port`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-ops.html?q=current-error-port#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-error-port%29%29) instead / also.